# Facebook sharer.php can't pass t value

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Read the documentation but still having a problem properly formatting my name value pairs so that my message gets passed and show up in a user's timeline. For instance, this works

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=apple.com
```

But in the following 'hello' does not show up.... Using ';amp' instead of '&' makes no difference.

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=apple.com&t=hello
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Using `u` pulls the meta data from the page as it appears under developers.facebook.com/tool/debug.

You can try using the old format

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=hello&p%5Burl%5D=google.com`